# No Drives - While Windows 7 Installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot

My Friend laptop had some issue while `ON` the laptop, It shows product logo,boot option everything  After that it shows blackscreen with blinking cursor.
so try to repair startup using OS - Repair Option, its not working, 
From OS Recovery Option - Choose `cmd` to list the disk, it only shows my pendrive

Even though I'll try to Install os

> "No drives were found. Click Load Driver to provide a mass storage driver for installation."

Is this because of Hard Drive Failure?

Comment: 2 possibilities: Could be because the HDD is dead (check from BIOS). If not dead / visible on BIOS - It could be because the Windows 7 installer does not have the correct driver to process/detect the HDD. You can load additional driver (just have it read in the same pen drive, or a 2nd pen drive) and install it there.

Comment: Thank you @Darius for your reply, did you mean that was lack of system reserved partition

Comment: Even before that. Does the BIOS detect your HDD? That should be first check (for possible hardware failure).

Comment: If you confirms that HDD is shown in the BIOS - then Windows 7 installer USB simply does not have the correct driver to be able to read your HDD. Windows 7 is considerably old and as much as it try to pack various generic drivers - if you install it on an unsupported hardware (newer hardware) - it may not have the correct driver to initialize your HDD and able to interact with it.

Comment: Yes @Darius bios detect HDD

Comment: You will need to load the drivers for SATA controller for your hardware. Put the driver ready in your windows 7 USB (or separate USB) and win 7 installer will be able to load it from there.